# Use switch statement in Swift to change view controller

Tags: ios, swift

I've just started learning swift and have hit my first major roadblock in creating my iOS app.

The situation is, I have an initial view controller that contains a slide in menu. I am using a function within this view controller that has switch statements to allow a user to select from a slide out menu. E.g. "Home", "About" and "Image list".

Right now I have no error messages and when I select "about" from the slide-out menu, it just loads what appears to be the default screen.

Generally, the problem I'm trying to solve is:
**Using the code below, what is the best way to load a separate view?**
This may be an harder question without seeing all of my code, but what might lead to the `.about` switch statement not loading the expected view?

For reference `case .imageList` is where I started and works for a quick view.

```
    func transitionToNew(_ menuType: MenuType) {
        //let title = String(describing: menuType).capitalized
        topView?.removeFromSuperview()

        switch menuType {
        case .about:
            let view = UIView()
            let profileVC = AboutViewController()
            view.addSubview(profileVC.view)
            // Method creates a parent-child relationship between current view controller and profileVC
            addChild(profileVC)
        case .imageList:
            let view = UIView()
            view.backgroundColor = .white
            view.frame = self.view.bounds
            self.view.addSubview(view)
            self.topView = view
            self.title = "Image List"

        default:
            self.title = nil // Reset title to match launch screen
            break
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of loading a view as you state here 'Using the code below, what is the best way to load a separate view?', you should be loading another view Controller.

You can create a parent-child relation between view controllers by either making the parent VC present the child VC modally or add all view controllers to a Navigation controller that manages a stack of related view controllers.

Here are a couple of approaches.

1. Load the new view controller (for eg: About VC) as a modal view
   controller. (mainVC.present)

   ```
   switch menuType {
   case .about:
       let profileVC = AboutViewController()
       viewController.present(profileVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
   default:
       self.title = nil // Reset title to match launch screen
       break
   }
   ```
2. Load the main VC in navigation controller and make
   the navigation controller push the new view onto the navigation
   stack.

   ```
   switch menuType {
   case .about:
       let profileVC = AboutViewController()
   self.navigationController?.pushViewController(targetViewController!, animated: true) //Note : for this to work when you create your main (parentVC) that should also be embeded in navigation controller.
   ```

Comment: For approach #2, I'm getting *Instance member 'present' cannot be used on type 'viewController'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?*

Comment: @Aus_10 I have edited my answer, hope it makes sense. When you are using a navigation controller, the nav controller has a stack of viewcontrollers. You push and pop view controllers on this stack.

Comment: I figured it out...I did need the modal method except it need to be a child member not "viewController"

Answer (score 0):

You need to set **frame** property in the view of .about case.

Answer (score 0):

*Swift 5.1*

```
switch menuType {
case .about:
   let profileVC = AboutViewController()
   self.present(profileVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
case .imageList:
   let imageVC = ImageViewController()
   self.present(imageVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
case default:
   break
}
```